# WLST Embedded Mode - t3s protocol

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x, wlst

I am trying to connect to Weblogic ( Remote) Admin server through WLST embedded Mode - using WLSTInterpreter.java

I am trying to connect through `t3s` protocol . In other modes we use to pass the following parameters in JVM options

like

```
java -Dweblogic.security.TrustKeyStore=DemoTrust 
-Dweblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStoreFileName=xxxx.jks  
-Dweblogic.security.CustomTrustKeyStoreType=JKS
-Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true 
-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom  weblogic.WLST <actual script>
```

But , in embedded mode we are creating instance for WLSTInterpreter and connecting like this

```
interpreter.exec("connect('user','password','t3://host:port')");
```

Even though i am passing jvm arguments while executing my class , it is still throw bad certificates.. any clue ? . How to pass Jvm options in Embedded mode.